# Why does Mathematica seem to give this `DSolveDispatchODE` error seemingly at random with `DSolve` despite working

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I have tried the following 4 test cases for `DSolve`:

1. Gives correct solution with `DSolveDispatchODE` error

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == -y[x]* x, y[0] == 1} , y[x], x]
(* Attributes: Symbol DSolveDispatchODE not found *)
(* {{y[x] -> E^(-(x^2/2))}} *)
```

2. Gives correct solution with `DSolveDispatchODE` error

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == -y[x], y[0] == 1} , y[x], x]
(* Attributes: Symbol DSolveDispatchODE not found *)
(* {{y[x] -> E^-x}} *)
```

3. Gives correct solution with `DSolveDispatchODE` error

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == -y[x]^2*x, y[0] == 1} , y[x], x]
(* Attributes: Symbol DSolveDispatchODE not found *)
(* {{y[x] -> 2/(2 + x^2)}} *)
```

4. Gives correct solution without `DSolveDispatchODE` error

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == -y[x]^2*x, y[0] == 1} , y[x], x]
(* {{y[x] -> 2/(2 + x^2)}} *)
```

I've done a bit of googling, but I can't seem to determine what this is. Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works for me. I do not see **Attributes: Symbol DSolveDispatchODE not found** in any of the examples you give. V 13.1 on windows 10.

Comment: Ahh, I'm on V12 on my laptop, so this must be a version thing. Thanks @Nasser!

Comment: No error for me on V12.3/Macbook Pro. It seems unlikely that `Attributes` would be called on ``DSolve`DSolveDispatchODE``. It does not show up in a trace.

Comment: For further reference, I'm on the `Linux/Unix` version